# Is it Possible to make "Forget password immediately" the default when opening LUKS encrypted partition?

Tags: luks, dmcrypt

When a LUKS encrypted partition pops up the unlock window it gives 3 options for how to remember the password. The "Remember password until you logout" is always ticked by default. Is there a way to make "Forget password immediately" the default?

```
Enter a passphrase to unlock the volume:

[ ] Forget password immediately
[x] Remember password until you logout
[ ] Remember forever
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I would like to do the exact same thing, but I have only been able to find posts/questions explaining how to auto-mount encrypted disk, or something similar.

Comment: related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615408/how-to-disable-remember-forever-option-in-mounting-encrypted-disks?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the setting comes from your desktop environment, e.g. GNOME. Not related to LUKS or the encryption.

If GNOME is your desktop environment, you should change GNOME settings. One way is to install `dconf-editor` by

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

You might be able to find the relevant default setting there.

**Edited**
I am editting this message as per recommendations provided by [felinira](https://askubuntu.com/users/967596/felinira) (see replies to this message):

> For modern versions of gnome (everything from the last decade) you should use dconf-editor instead. The key is org.gnome.shell.remember-mount-password. From the description: "The shell will request a password when an encrypted device or a remote filesystem is mounted. If the password can be saved for future use a “Remember Password” checkbox will be present. This key sets the default state of the checkbox."

Comment: For modern versions of gnome (everything from the last decade) you should use dconf-editor instead. The key is org.gnome.shell.remember-mount-password. From the description: "The shell will request a password when an encrypted device or a remote filesystem is mounted. If the password can be saved for future use a “Remember Password” checkbox will be present. This key sets the default state of the checkbox."

Comment: @felinira I'm on Arch linux with some gnome services, but that key is not present in my case. Even though I still have the dialog when mounting my LUKS drives. I figure I could probably add the key, but can't find any information to do so.

Comment: Per this: https://superuser.com/questions/1625494/how-to-default-nemo-to-forget-luks-password it is hardcoded, if you know better, what is the name of the schema key?