# Change the default option to "Forget password immediately" when mounting a Luks usb drive

Tags: usb-drive, luks

I would like to do exactly what [this poster](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509906/possible-to-make-forget-password-immediately-the-default-when-opening-luks-enc) wants to do:

> When a LUKS encrypted partition pops up the unlock window it gives 3
>   options for how to remember the password. The "Remember password until
>   you logout" is always ticked by default. Is there a way to make
>   "Forget password immediately" the default?
>
> ```
> Enter a passphrase to unlock the volume:
> [] Forget password immediately
> [x]Remember password until you logout
> [] Remember forever
> ```

Unfortunately, there hasn't been any answer to this question, so I created a new question. (Let me know if I wasn't supposed to do it this way!)

Comment: For people coming from Google: If you want to forget it after accidentally choosing "Remember forever" you can follow [the steps explained here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/615408/how-to-disable-remember-forever-option-in-mounting-encrypted-disks).

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing, but judging from [a similar question that was answered on StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7294/change-default-for-nautilus-file-manager-from-forget-password-immediately), there isn't a way at present. It looks like the default behavior was changed from "Forget password immediately" to "Remember password until you log out", but absent some way to tweak this, the new default isn't going to work for some of us either.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box way to change the default for this menu option.

However, there is a work around, where you create a script to detect X window and then have the system send an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> signal that will switch it to immediately forget.

You can also set up a script to `udiskctl --lock` or `udiskctl --unlock` the drive, which will get rid of the file manager integration, thus the security risk of saving it to the keyring, if by a non-root user.

As for me,

```
udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb1
```

Decrypts USB and mounts it.

```
umount -l /media/john/usbfolder
```

is a lazy umount with mapping equal to mounted path and

```
udisksctl lock -b /dev/sdb1
```

encrypts the USB.
It gets a little more complicated since the dialog window does not have a lot of metadata to manipulate with X.