# How to disable "Remember forever" option in mounting encrypted disks

Tags: disk, luks

Whenever you mount an LUKS encrypted disk, Ubuntu gives you 3 options:

- Forget immediately
- Remember for this session
- Remember forever

I wanted to know how to reset this choice after choosing the "Remember forever" one, and make the window appear again.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/509906/possible-to-make-forget-password-immediately-the-default-when-opening-luks-enc?rq=1 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/59487/how-to-configure-lvm-luks-to-autodecrypt-partition

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was looking for a similar information and came across this question of yours. Actually I was trying to understand how was this "remembered password" stored, and if it was safely stored.

Then I stumbled into [@Gilles answer to a similar question in Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108242/how-does-nautilus-store-passwords-on-ubuntu).

Based on that answer, you can go to "Show applications" -> "Passwords and keys". Your stored password should be found under "Login", and can be deleted.

[image: screenshot]

> Under the default configuration in Ubuntu, passwords are stored in the
>   [GNOME keyring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring). This
>   applies to all passwords stored by Nautilus, as well as most other
>   applications including web browsers.
>
> (Let me reiterate: *default configuration*, *most*. This can be
>   changed and there are applications that don't support the Gnome
>   keyring.)
>
> You can use the [Seahorse](http://packages.ubuntu.com/seahorse) GUI
>   program or the
>   [`secret-tool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/secret-tool.1.html)
>   command line utility to view and modify the contents of the keyring.
>
> There is some [official documentation about Gnome
>   Keyring](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring), including a
>   [“security
>   philosophy”](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/SecurityPhilosophy)
>   and a more concrete [security
>   architecture](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/StoringSecrets).
>
> Data in memory (“Remember password until you logout”) is present in
>   the memory of the `gnome-keyring-daemon` process, which allows any
>   process running as your user to query it. Gnome-keyring [avoids
>   swapping](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Memory) if
>   possible; however, if you have any encrypted storage, you should have
>   encrypted swap, because the programs that manipulate the confidential
>   data could themselves be swapped out.
>
> Data on disk (“Remember forever”) is stored in the file
>   `~/.gnome2/keyrings/login.keyring`. It is
>   [encrypted](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/KeyringFormats)
>   with a key that's derived from a password; normally, that's your login
>   password, and Ubuntu is set up to [unlock the keyring with your login
>   password](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Pam). The key
>   is derived from the password with a [salted, slow
>   hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)
>   but I don't know exactly what the derivation function is.

Comment: "Chrome Safe Storage" stores the LUKS password for all your encrypted USB drives? That app doesn't even seem to let you delete anything. Selecting one or all, and then doing Edit->Delete has no effect on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

A few more 18.10 tips in addition to [gusbrs answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/724766/52975):

- if the password list is empty, try going into:

  - Menu
  - View
  - Show Any
- LUKS passwords show as: "Encryption Passphrase for <disk name>"

Comment: That didn't help in my case. I couldn't see any LUKS passphrases in seahorse. However, `gnome-keyring-daemon -r` reset the passphrase prompt, both in Thunar and in gnome-disks, and seemingly cleared the remembered passphrase for that drive. Shrug. See [Question 1059797](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059797/ubuntu-16-04-encrypted-usb-disk-key-not-showing-up-in-seahorse)

Comment: @MartinSpacek ok, thanks for this info. I'm not sure if all those method use the same keystore or not. Sometimes it is best not to know ;-)